# Customers not receiving push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have been sending push notifications from firebase to iOS app but some users are receiving it and some are not receiving it. What could be breaking here? Can anyone help?

It seems like APNS is not delivering just the push notifications to some users.

Comment: There are a lot of cases when user can't receive push notification. And from Apple: "Because the delivery of remote notifications is **not guaranteed**, never include sensitive data or data that can be retrieved by other means in your payload"

Comment: Maybe some of the users disabled this app's notifications.